# codeigniter 2 typehinting loaded model IN PHPStorm 2016.3.3

Tags: php, codeigniter, type-hinting

Let's pretend I am stuck in a time capsule in 2012 and I am still working in codeigniter 2 how can I typehint a loaded model in my controller so my editor find the functions etc.

my model is named `profilemodel.php`

I currently do this in the controller constructor:

```
/** var profilemodel $profileModel */
$profileModel = $this->load->model('profilemodel');
```

And I do this in a method in the controller:

```
$profileModel->getUserByEmail($user);
```

But this doesn't seem to be working

Anyone has any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Please specify what IDE and which version your are using with Codeigniter 2 in the first sentence so that people can easily unserstand what you're looking for. I would also suggest to include this in the title, e.g. "How to enable type hinting in Codeigniter 2 with <IDE>?".

Comment: @aux Thanks for the tip! I updated OP